# Designing a constant current pulse circuit

Tags: transformer, pwm, bjt, current-source, constant-current

I'm looking for help designing a constant current pulse through a variable load impedance of 10-100k (R4). The ideal response is shown below. This waveform was measured from an off the shelf instrument without access to the design files.

The attractive component is the square wave that it generates. It spends a solid couple of milliseconds at my intended current.

[image: Ideal circuit response]

My current design results in a circuit response as shown below with a sharp rise then fall (not ideal).

[image: Circuit response]

I'm hoping for my circuit response to more closely match that of the response shown above. What modifications could be made in order to square out the waveform?

[image: Circuit schematic]

Comment: Your ideal response looks rather less than ideal so could you specify what it is about the trailing edge slowly decaying back to zero that is at all attractive to you? What circuit produced the "ideal" waveform?

Comment: Sure, the ideal waveform was measured from an off the shelf instrument without access to the design files. The attractive component is the square wave that it generates. It spends a solid couple of milliseconds at my intended current.

Comment: Is the ideal response required to integrate to something near zero?

Comment: If so, you might try differentiating an asymmetric triangle wave.

Comment: IMO it has to be at least 2nd order, or maybe more. You circuit has a 2st order response.

Comment: Are you liking the slightly underdamped response at the other side of your first graph? Or is that response something you'd also like changed? Andy brought this up. I'm not sure there is an answer here yet. You merely talked about the part you liked. Which wasn't all of what we can see there. Finally, is R4 10k to 100k? Or 10 to 100k? I can't tell. And what's the magnitude of the current you want? Or is that variable, too?

Comment: I'm not too concerned with the underdamped response on either result. The design goal is for a constant current pulse around of about 10mA over a variable load for a duration of around 200us. R4 is a 10k pot used to bias the BJT.

Comment: @zciwor I think I see a fixed R4 resistor on the other end of a transformer. Are we looking at the same schematic? Also, you write in your question, "variable load impedance of 10-100k (R4)", which sounds odd if what you mean is biasing a BJT. I do see the X1 pot there of course (and did before.) And the value is 10k as you say. But I'm kind of muddled up now by what you wrote, show in the schematic, and are now saying. Oh, well.

Comment: You have a 1:8 transformer with 2.8 V drive, ~22V output. Why not design with a 30 V supply and leave out the transformer